# Contribution Page - Unlink last year's contributions?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

I am new to the position of keeping our website up-to-date. The previous person told me that I could edit over previous versions of pages so we don't have multiple pages that are similiar of events we do each year. I updated one of our contribution pages (YLS Supports Income Programs), however I notice on the widget page that it is pulling the contributions from last year's event. Is there a way to unlink that so we can start fresh at $0 this year? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you,
Kim

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes -> make a copy instead of editing!

```
Events -> Manage Events -> under the more (on the far right) -> hit Copy.
```

This will copy all your settings/etc but will not copy your participants. Contribution pages: very similar -> same thing!

```
Contributions -> Manage Contribution Pages -> under the more (on the far right) -> hit Make a copy.
```